# Deploying Django app on Yocto

Tags: django, yocto, cherokee

I am currently working on a project that requires to deploy a Django Application to a ConnectCore 6 UL SBC Pro which runs a custom version of Yocto project.

I have been having a lot of issues to deploy my app onto this device, I would like to know if anyone has ever achieved to do this on Yocto.

So far I am trying to deploy my application using Cherokee and it is not as easy as they let you think!

*** UPDATE ***

I went for Apache2 and added mod-wsgi that is available on openembedded.com. I have need able to access my development server using the following command :

```
python3.5 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Also allow any host adding * to the settings.py